# Can't execute sh script with parameters in Ansible

Tags: shell, ansible, sh

I'm trying to start an installation script that already exists on the remote host with ansible playbook. There also some parametrs required.

```
- hosts: myhost
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Running an installation script
      command: sh /home/user/install.sh --param1 'param1' --param2 'param2' --param3 'param3' --param4 'param4'
```

But it doesn't work. When I trying to start playbook I get this output:

```
fatal: [myhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["sh", "/home/user/install.sh", "--param1", "param1", "----param1", "--param1", "--param3", "param3", "--param4", "param4"], "delta": "0:00:00.002254", "end": "2019-04-17 11:27:13.063837", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2019-04-17 11:27:13.061583", "stderr": "/home/user/install.sh: 4: set: Illegal option -o pipefail", "stderr_lines": ["/home/user/install.sh: 4: set: Illegal option -o pipefail"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Comment: Is the interpreter sh or bash. Also is the script working the same way manually?

Comment: have you tried using the shell module?

Comment: Interpreter is sh and yes, this script with parameters working if I starting it on the node manually. The shell module was an option but I found answer about using "command: sh" as better solution for running script that already exists on the node. However, "-c" option helped me out.

Answer (score 3):

The script fails with this message:

> "stderr_lines": ["/home/user/install.sh: 4: set: Illegal option -o pipefail"]

Try to read the command from a string. See [sh](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html).

```
command: sh -c "/home/user/install.sh --param1 'param1' ..."
```

Qouting from man sh

> The -c option causes the commands to be read from the string operand
>        instead of from the standard input.  Keep in mind that this option only
>        accepts a single string as its argument, hence multi-word strings must be
>        quoted.

Answer (score 1):

As the doc suggests (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html) you could use command like this:

```
- name: Running an installation script
      command: /home/user/install.sh --param1 'param1' --param2 'param2' --param3 'param3' --param4 'param4'
```

If you have a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in your script, this should be no problem.

Another solution would be to use script (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/script_module.html) like so:

```
- name: Running an installation script
  script: /home/user/install.sh --param1 param1 --param2 param2 --param3 param3 --param4 param4
```

Let me hear if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use shell module instead of command module for passing the arguments to your linux command specifically for script ansible has a script module

- name: Run a script only if file.txt exists on the remote node
  script: /some/local/remove_file.sh --some-argument 1234
  args:
  removes: /the/removed/file.txt

and for linux commands

like :   shell: "curl --socks5 localhost:9000 http://www.ansible.com"

and for more details refer

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html